# How to tell if crankshaft sensor or Camshaft sensor is bad

Tags: honda, troubleshooting, civic, crank-position-sensor, cam-position-sensor

I have a 2006 Honda Civic I was driving it and was On my way! To my friends shop I mad a turn and it felt like the transmission went out of fear while I was accelerating than while I was trying to get it in to gear it felt like it was loosing power like I was giving it gas and there was no acceleration
I tried to turn car off and on and wouldn't turn back over so my friend said it's either camshaft sensor or crankshaft sensor how do I check to see which one I need

Comment: best way to test is with a scope but depending on the sensor design you can use a multimeter. if it's a digital signal you can just backprobe the signal wire while cranking the engine and the voltage reading should be half the supply voltage.

Answer (score 1):

Get an OBD2 reader (compatible to your vehicle) and check the codes - it will tell you what is at fault.

Comment: What would the person do with it once they have a reader?

Comment: plug it in to the OBD2 port (wherever that happens to be on that vehicle) then ignition on and read the codes - but one has to navigate the menu system which may depend on the reader manufacturer...

Answer (score 0):

Huh?  "so my friend said it's either camshaft sensor or crankshaft sensor.."   Not sure what that is based on.

For an engine to run, it needs three things:  1) Spark   2) Fuel  and 3) air. (in the right amount at the right time...)

On your 2006 vehicle, there is an engine control computer that controls spark (timing) and controls fuel/air mixture (via fuel injectors).  That computer is a pretty decent tool.  It reads a whole lot of inputs.  If it sees something "wrong" it sets a diagnostic code. Those codes are stored in memory.  When it sees something "wrong" it sets a "check engine light" to tell you that something is wrong.

With that said. Dave, is it just possible for you to turn the key on, wait 60 seconds and tell us if the check engine light is on?  The check engine light is in the instrument cluster, just on the other side of the steering wheel.

If the light is on, you will need an OnBoard Diagnostic (OBD2) code reader tool.   It sounds like the car won't start now, so you can't use the free OBD2 reader service provided by many US based autoparts stores.. You will have to purchase or borrow a tool from somebody.  They seem to cost between $60 and $100 to purchase from an autoparts store, and much less on line.  I bought an blue tooth device on Amazon for $15.  Obviously, this is the same answer as Solar Mike proposed.  (His answer definitely is an improvement over mine.)

With that said, however there is one comment of note.  Not every fault that precludes an engine from starting up will set an OBD code.  The engine computer is depending on feedback from an array of sensors.  In my experience, its poor on identifying if the engine is getting spark.  Yes the computer sends out a 'spark now' signal, but it doesn't have a great way to watch a spark plug to see if a real spark was generated.  It may not tell you if you have a totally plugged up air cleaner or a plugged exhaust pipe.

It absolutely WILL tell you if a crankshaft or camshaft sensor is not operating correctly.  (and by the way those are hall effect sensors... quite easy to test... hook up wires to volt-ohm meter, set to voltage and move a pair of pliers near the sensor.. you will see reading jump).

I doubt the camshaft/crankshaft theory. We work on known facts, based on careful troubleshooting here..

Step 1.  Is engine light on?
Step 2.  If engine light on, what codes are set on OBD2?
Step 3.  If engine light not on, start by inspecting engine for obvious things (out of gas?  broken wire?  Loose terminals on battery?)
Step 4.  Continue to inspect items that don't set codes... and I'd start with ignition system. (Some vehicles will set codes here, but not all...)

Good luck with it...